# why does my setup running "buildozer -v android debug" results in: command failed?

Tags: android, python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to create an .apk file according to the following tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gNpSuE01qE&t=1417s

However, when I execute "buildozer -v android debug" as done in the video at 19:53, I get the error message as below.

I run Pycharm on a Windows 10 device. I run a virtual environment in Pycharm which uses Python 3.8.2. I have java 14.0.2 2020-07-14 installed.
To run buildozer, I installed Ubuntu via the Windows Subsystem for Linux. The installation of the Ubuntu system is default and it came with Python 3.10.2 and I installed openjdk 17.0.8.1.

Because I assumed it might have something to do with the python version, I added the python version in the buildozer.spec file. I also tried changing the ANDROIDAPI level to 21 as per another stackoverflow question, but to no avail. I changed it back and get the following error message. Can someone please help me to solve the error?

I can upload a copy of my buildozer.spec file or more information if required.

```
Command
failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myprogram', '--bootstrap=sdl2',
         '--requirements=python3==3.8.2,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs',
         '--color=always',
         '--storage-dir=/mnt/c/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/<myprogram>/<subprogram>/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a',
         '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
ENVIRONMENT:
SHELL = '/bin/bash'
WSL2_GUI_APPS_ENABLED = '1'
WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
NAME = 'DESKTOP-368ASLO'
PWD = '/mnt/c/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/<myprogram>/<subprogram>'
LOGNAME = '<user>'
HOME = '/home/<user>'
LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/359_interop'
LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
TERM = 'xterm-256color'
LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
USER = '<user>'
DISPLAY = ':0'
SHLVL = '1'
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000/'
WSLENV = ''
XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
PATH = (
    '/home/<user>/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/<user>/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program '
    'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2204.2.33.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program '
    'Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common '
    'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
    'Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files '
    '(x86)/Calibre2/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL '
    'Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client '
    'SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL '
    'Server/150/Tools/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL '
    'Server/150/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL '
    'Server/150/DTS/Binn/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Azure Data '
    'Studio/bin:/mnt/c/Users/bendi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/swigwin-3.0.12:/mnt/c/Program '
    'Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files '
    '(x86)/GnuPG/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
    'Files/Java/jdk-14.0.2/bin:/mnt/c/Users/bendi/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
    'Files/Azure Data '
    'Studio/bin:/mnt/c/Users/bendi/PycharmProjects/swigwin-3.0.12:/mnt/c/Users/bendi/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/home/<user>/.local/bin/')
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
PULSE_SERVER = 'unix:/mnt/wslg/PulseServer'
_ = '/home/<user>/.local/bin/buildozer'
OLDPWD = '/home/<user>'
PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/<user>/.buildozer/android/packages'
ANDROIDSDK = '/home/<user>/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
ANDROIDNDK = '/home/<user>/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
ANDROIDAPI = '31'
ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'

Buildozer failed to execute the last command. The error might be hidden in the log
above this error. Please read the full log, and search for it before raising an
    issue with buildozer itself. In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: I solved the problem. I think it is because I ran 3 commands in the Ubuntu CLI interface. 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8